# Adding a number at the end of the directory C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to add a number to the end of the directory
for example, if the directory was called test, I want the other directory to be made test1 and then test2.

So basically, I want to make a directory which carries on from the previous by putting a number at the end. So it checks which directory was the last one e.g. Test1 and makes Test2

Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste some of your code?

Comment: I don't have any. I just want to learn how to do it thanks. Sorry if I'm being a unhelpful, I just started learning the language.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple: You start with `"test"` and append numbers until you find a name that doesn't exist:

```
var baseName = "test";
var name = baseName;
int i = 1;
while(Directory.Exists(name))
{
    name = baseName + i;
    ++i;
}

return name;
```